# Enter key by ALT key

Tags: keyboard

as you may know by *ALT keys + numbers* we can write special characters like:

```
ALT + 178: ▓
```

my question is, Is there an alt key for ENTER key on keyboard?

thanks for helping!

Comment: That depend on your application use case.  So can you elaborate the question

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ALT + 013** is carriage return i.e. ENTER on keyboard.